# Django Database Design: Many-to-Many, Foreign Key, or neither?

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-models

A noob question. I'm putting together my first database and have the following design problem: I have a class which defines a book (e.g. it's title) and a class which defines a page (e.g. it's design).

The table for the class book would look so:

```
Title        | PAGE1        | PAGE2        | PAGE3
Book-One     | SAMPLE1-UUID | SAMPLE2-UUID | SAMPLE3-UUID
Book-Two     | SAMPLE4-UUID | SAMPLE5-UUID | SAMPLE6-UUID
```

The table for the class page:

```
UUID         | FONT         | CONTENTS etc.
SAMPLE1-UUID | Times        | Example
SAMPLE2-UUID | Arial        | Example Two
SAMPLE3-UUID | Verdena      | Example Three
```

Now, as each page is unique and can't be re-used in another book, I can't use a many-to-many relationship for Pages. I could use Foreign-Key to link the two tables, i.e. link SAMPLE1-UUID of the Books Table with the SAMPLE1-UUID of the Pages Table. This has the advantage of not creating the same entry twice.

However, I don't like the idea of having a fixed amount of rows for my pages. In the above example for the class Book, I'd have to define a certain set of Pages, like PAGE1, PAGE2, PAGE3, PAGE4, ... PAGE99. Ideally, all I need is a flexible list of pages for my book class, like so:

```
Name         | Pages
Book-One     | "SAMPLE1-UUID, SAMPLE2-UUID"
Book-Two     | "SAMPLE4-UUID, SAMPLE5-UUID, SAMPLE6-UUID"
```

Pages would be a simple CharField and its contents would be a list. But then I have the problem that the two tables are not linked anymore and that I'd have to create each entry twice (i.e. I would have to enter SAMPLE1-UUID in both the pages and books table).

Is there another way to design this database? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll suggest you don't have the pages as columns:

The table for the class book would look so with book only information:

```
Title        | ISBN         
Book-One     | XXXXXXXXXXXX 
Book-Two     | YYYYYYYYYYYY
```

The table for the class page:

```
BOOKID       |PAGE_NUM | FONT         | CONTENTS
1            |1        | Times        | Example
1            |2        | Arial        | Example Two
2            |1        | Verdena      | Example Three
```

Your class design would look something like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Page(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    page_num = models.IntegerField()
    font = models.charField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
```

You can go ahead and have contraints so that a book and page_num does not repeat for instance but this can be a good start.

Comment: Thanks Keni. My only problem is when I log into my Django Admin interface, I won't see what pages are in each book. Daniel Roseman suggested using my_book.page_set.all() but I'm not sure how this would translate in this case. Can I add this to my admin.py? Regardless of the admin interface, how would you get a list of all pages for the book with the ID 1? Thanks so much for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: @n.evermind `admin.StackedInline` is what you're looking for. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=....)

class Page(models.Model):
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book)
    number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I don't understand your book table example: Do you want a column for page1 and an other column for page2? That looks very strange.

Comment: Thanks Guettli. Yes, ideally I would like to have a table which lists all pages and their layout attributes - no matter what book they are in. E.g. if I have two books and each as got 5 pages, my pages table will have 10 entries. Or is this bad data base design too? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood how a foreign key works. It's not a "fixed amount of rows" - just the opposite, in fact.

As guettli shows in his answer, a ForeignKey field is a one-to-many relationship, defined on the "many" side. That is, with the ForeignKey defined on Page pointing at Book, each Page has one Book, but a Book has as many Pages as you like.

So, using the Django ORM, if you have a book object and you want to get all its pages, you just do `my_book.page_set.all()`.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I messed up the "many" side with the "one" side. How helpful. Makes much more sense now. So in other words, when I enter a book in my database, I don't care about its pages. My only problem now: If I have a look at a book in my django admin database interface, I won't see what pages it has got. Or can I add this via book.page_set.all()? In any case, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For the change form, you can use [inline modeladmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to show/edit all pages for a book.